# Responsvie website width

Tags: html, css, web

When coding width for responsive, is it preferable to round off the value or specify the value as close as possible?

For example:

Base on my calculation my width is 67.328699%(left div) and 32.84%(right div)

or should I just round it off to
67%(left div) and 33%(right div)
which will add up to 100%?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this.  First, due to the nature of foating point arithmetic, you're probably not going to get an EXACT number, so rounding isn't going to break anything. You're never going to be exactly right anyway. Smarter people have written about this point: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Second, think about what the number actually 67.328699% means.  you're trying to accurately define a size down to a millionth of a percent, or in other words a hundred millionth of your entire screen width. How much are you actually gaining by doing that?

Also, because of the limitations of floating point math, it's likely that if you make the widths sum to an exact 100%, when the user changes the screen width or sometimes simply with other resolutions, you're going to have the divs jumping.  Sometimes they will be on the same line, sometimes they will not.  I suggest you have them add up to slightly less than 100%.

edit:  on another note, I would have a discussion with your designer and ask why they made such odd proportions.  They should make designs around technology.  Your job isn't to force the technology to fit a design.

Comment: You're welcome.  im glad it helped.  Browsers also round numbers differently, so sometimes extra decimal places are disregarded or rounded for you anyway

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question, But I think there is no matter, because in small screens the percentage you round is very very small. But looking at the most famous responsive design of twitter bootstrap [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com) they don't round up the values.

I suggest you too look at bootstrap's grid system it will help you a lot in designing responsive pages.

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 decimals would be fine, but keep in mind the box-model when you set the percentages(it's a good idea to always use `box-sizing:border-box`)

Answer (score 0):

I would specify it rounded off, personally.

But if you are creating a responsive muti-column layout, I would suggest using a grid system like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)